# Flask can access yfinance API on Localhost but crash on Heroku (No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted)

Tags: flask, heroku, localhost, yfinance, pandas-datareader

I managed to complete building my flash app and deploy it on Heroku. However, when I try to use yfinance and pandas_datareader, the app returns nothing. I have already incorporated the override code and yfinance, pdr are both of the latest versions. Moreover, when I run the flask app on localhost it works just fine accessing yahoo finance API...I don't understand why it stops working once the app is running on heroku.

**The same code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3, uuid, io
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt 
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr 
import os, openpyxl
import smtplib, imghdr, time
from email.message import EmailMessage

yf.pdr_override()
start = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)
now = dt.datetime(2023,4,6)

dfeg = pdr.get_data_yahoo('TEAM', start, now)
print(dfeg)
```

**Localhost console:**

```
                  Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date
2021-01-04  234.500000  234.500000  224.904999  231.559998  231.559998  1051200
2021-01-05  232.000000  235.350006  229.009995  234.419998  234.419998  1106200
2021-01-06  228.919998  230.199997  223.929993  224.479996  224.479996  1601700
2021-01-07  228.029999  233.889999  228.020004  233.380005  233.380005  1309500
2021-01-08  236.000000  238.000000  231.830002  235.479996  235.479996   804200
...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...      ...
2023-03-30  161.520004  162.119995  158.899994  160.589996  160.589996   966300
2023-03-31  161.759995  171.839996  160.460007  171.169998  171.169998  1645700
2023-04-03  169.320007  170.669998  161.789993  163.919998  163.919998  1347800
2023-04-04  164.639999  169.500000  164.220001  166.490005  166.490005  1125900
2023-04-05  165.369995  165.559998  156.589996  156.990005  156.990005  1536700
```

**Heroku Logs:**

```
2023-04-09T21:49:00.706293+00:00 app[web.1]: 1 Failed download:
2023-04-09T21:49:00.706294+00:00 app[web.1]: - TEAM: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted
2023-04-09T21:49:00.706846+00:00 app[web.1]: Empty DataFrame
2023-04-09T21:49:00.706846+00:00 app[web.1]: Columns: [Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume]
2023-04-09T21:49:00.706846+00:00 app[web.1]: Index: []
2023-04-09T21:49:00.708456+00:00 app[web.1]: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I tried to update yfinance and pandas_datareader...didn't work because they're both of the latest versions.

I have also tried other methods from pdr such as pdr.get_data_fed() and it WORKED! So I am suspecting this is a pdr.get_data_yahoo() problem?

My code already contains the override method.

I really don't understand why my localhost can fetch the data but it stops working on heroku.